# Extract hash from file name

Tags: sed, hashsum

When archiving certain data we encode the archive's sha1 HASH within the file name so as to determine the integrity of the archive.

I am trying to find a way to automate the integrity check by extracting the HASH out of the file name:

```
echo myid123_2019-08-31_b7769c0e22c7f75b2935afad499852630ca83145.tar.xz | sed -n 's/^.*\([[:xdigit:]]{40}\).*$/\1/p'

echo myid123_2019-08-31_b7769c0e22c7f75b2935afad499852630ca83145.tar.xz | sed -n 's/^.*\([0-9a-fA-F]{40}\).*$/\1/p'
```

Both tests above return no results.  Am I missing something?

I would prefer to test for the HASH explicitly, rather then by elimination or position as the filename format can vary.  In any case the hash would be delimited by non-hash characters.

**Follow-up:**

Thanks for the help.

This is the final product I was looking to create:

```bash
function checkhash () { 
 for f in "$@"
  do 
   test -f $f || continue
   export HASH=$(echo ${f}| grep -o  '[0-9a-fA-F]\{32,128\}' )
   case $(echo -n ${HASH} | wc -c) in
    32)
       echo "${HASH} *${f}" | md5sum -c -
    ;;
    40)
       echo "${HASH} *${f}" | sha1sum -c -
    ;;
    56)
       echo "${HASH} *${f}" | sha224sum -c -
    ;;
    64)
       echo "${HASH} *${f}" | sha256sum -c -
    ;;
    96)
       echo "${HASH} *${f}" | sha384sum -c -
    ;;
    128)
       echo "${HASH} *${f}" | sha512sum -c -
    ;;
    *)
       echo "No Identified HASH found in filename: ${f}"
    ;;
   esac
 done
}
```

Comment: `{40}` isn't a quantifier in a sed basic regular expression - you'd need `sed -n 's/^.*\([[:xdigit:]]\{40\}\).*$/\1/p'` or `sed -En 's/^.*([[:xdigit:]]{40}).*$/\1/p'`. See [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 1):

Your examples suggest the hash string begins after the right-most underscore (`_`) character and ends before the left-most dot (`.`) character.

If you don't mind a two-step process, you can do it in bash like this:

```
file_name="myid123_2019-08-31_b7769c0e22c7f75b2935afad499852630ca83145.tar.xz"
name_hash="${file_name%%.*}"
hash="${name_hash##*_}"
echo "$hash"
```

produces

```
b7769c0e22c7f75b2935afad499852630ca83145
```

Comment: Again, this is biased on testing for something other then the hash/digest.  A hash is a fixed length, long-run sequence 32, 40, 56, 64, 96, or 128 characters (depending on the hash) consisting of hexadecimal case in-sensitive characters [0-9,a-f].  The only thing I can count on about the delimiter is that they will be non-hexadecimal characters.

Answer (score 1):

Let me offer something in `awk`:

```
echo myid123_2019-08-31_b7769c0e22c7f75b2935afad499852630ca83145.tar.xz | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $3}'
```

Comment: The problem here is that the test fixes on the delimiters which cannot be relied upon.  I need to test for the embedded HASH string in the file name.

Comment: @MarkC, provide REAL example and we can help you extract the hash.

Comment: You seem to have missed the point.  I got there eventually.  Thanks to everyone for their efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using grep would do a cleaner job:

```
$ a='myid123_2019-08-31_b7769c0e22c7f75b2935afad499852630ca83145.tar.xz'

$ echo "$a" | grep -o  '[0-9a-fA-F]\{40\}'

b7769c0e22c7f75b2935afad499852630ca83145
```

Please note that the `{...}` need quoting `\{...\}` in BRE.

Comment: THANKS.  This one seems to do the job quite nicely and keeps the code simple.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/([^_]*_){2}([^.]*).*/\2/' input_file
b7769c0e22c7f75b2935afad499852630ca83145
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "myid123_2019-08-31_b7769c0e22c7f75b2935afad499852630ca83145.tar.xz"|awk -F "_" '{gsub(/\..*/,"",$NF);print $NF}'
```

output

```
b7769c0e22c7f75b2935afad499852630ca83145
```